# Deleting duplicates but leaving one according to sorting in a different column

Tags: python, perl, awk, duplicates

I have a huge table with hundreds of thousands of rows and ten columns. I'd like to remove those duplicates according to column 4 (ID) but at the same time leaving the one that has the highest value on column 9 (score).

I tried this simple code in awk but it's apparently removing more lines than it should and even not picking all the duplicates..

```
sort -rnk 9 myfile.txt | awk -F"[. ]" '!a[$4]++' >filtered.txt
```

I'd appreciate any advice; I'd love to get this working on python or perl but I'm not very good at it (yet).

Thanks

Comment: Please show a few sample rows. I'm curious about your field separator

Comment: Im having trouble copying the table.. it's tab delimited though.

Comment: Well, if it's tab delimited, your field separator is wrong. Try `awk -F"\t"` and `sort -t $'\t'` (awk understands the 2 character string `"\" "t"` to mean a tab, but sort does not -- you need to give a literal tab to sort's -t)

Comment: ahah Oh man, that was a stupid mistake.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok, it certainly is a clever way to do it. I would write

```
awk -F"\t" '
    !($4 in max) || $9 > max[$4] {max[$4] = $9; line[$4] = $0} 
    END {for (key in line) print line[key]}
' myfile.txt
```

That approach should be pretty easy to translate to another language.

Comment: Thanks man. After fixing the "\t" issue, both codes give me the same result!

Comment: I'm curious about which one is faster. Can you time them?

Comment: Would it be possible to adapt this code to leave the highest value within two columns? lets say $9 and $11?

Answer (score 1):

Since the input file is so large, it would make sense to avoid requiring awk to store more information than necessary, so assuming sort is not prohibitively slow, you may wish to consider the following optimized variant of the sort/awk program, provided at least that the id is never the empty string:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k4,4 -rnk 9,9 | awk -F\\t 'key!=$4 {key=$4; print}'
```